# Toogle do not disturb mode with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts, notifications

Is there any way to set a keyboard shortcut to toggle do not disturb mode on/off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Disturb mode can be set via the dconf boolean value `org.pantheon.desktop.gala.notifications.do-not-disturb`.

You can toggle it with a script like this (saved as `~/bin/toggle_do-not-disturb`)

```
#!/bin/sh

KEY='/org/pantheon/desktop/gala/notifications/do-not-disturb'
dconf write $KEY $(if [ $(dconf read $KEY) = 'true' ]; then echo false; else echo true; fi)
```

Then you can assign this script to a custom hot key in *Settings/Keyboard* *Layout* tab:

[image]

Comment: This is _very_ useful!

Comment: Thanks. :) This is also useful if you want to override the "Do not disturb" mode temporarily for a notification You can set the KEY false, send a notification and set it to true again.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Elementary Odin, notifications are now in `io.elementary.notifications`. So, now the path changes to `/io/elementary/notifications/do-not-disturb`.

The new version for the script would  be:

```
#!/bin/sh

KEY='/io/elementary/notifications/do-not-disturb'
dconf write $KEY $(if [ $(dconf read $KEY) = 'true' ]; then echo false; else echo true; fi)
```

Source: [r/elementaryos](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/n8dez6/how_to_add_shortcuts_to_notifications_in_odin/) on Reddit.